# Drawing with js - fillstyle only works with hex value

Tags: javascript

I can only get fillstyle to work when I assign a hex color value. 
When I try other ways to use fillstyle I just get a black box.
I need to pass RGB values as variables.
Hopefully someone can tell me what am I missing
Here is a snip:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="DrawQuote" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<br><br>

<button onclick="draw()">Draw</button>    

<script>
function draw() {
  var c = document.getElementById("DrawQuote");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); 

  WallColour = "ES";
  switch (WallColour) {
    case "BL": Rwall = 25;  Gwall = 25;  Bwall = 25; break;
    case "ES": Rwall = 154; Gwall = 121; Bwall = 78; break;
    default:
    Rwall = 255; Gwall = 255; Bwall = 255; break;
  }

    // draw box
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";    // only one that works

//  doesn't work THIS IS THE ONE I NEED
//  ctx.fillstyle = "rgb(" + Rwall + ", " + Gwall + ", " + Bwall + ")";

//  doesn't work (rgb or hex)
//  var col = "rgb(44,66,77)";
//  var col = "#FF0000";
//  ctx.fillstyle = col;

//  doesn't work
//  ctx.fillstyle = "rgb(99, 99, 99)";

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);


}
</script>

<p><strong>The End</strong></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fillStyle` instead of `fillstyle`

```js
function draw() {
  var c = document.getElementById("DrawQuote");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); 

  WallColour = "ES";
  switch (WallColour) {
    case "BL": Rwall = 25;  Gwall = 25;  Bwall = 25; break;
    case "ES": Rwall = 154; Gwall = 121; Bwall = 78; break;
    default:
    Rwall = 255; Gwall = 255; Bwall = 255; break;
  }


  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + Rwall + ", " + Gwall + ", " + Bwall + ")";



ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);


}
```

```html
<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="DrawQuote" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<br><br>

<button onclick="draw()">Draw</button>    
<p><strong>The End</strong></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, (after changing capitalization to fillStyle) you'd just need to wrap rgb in tildes  ` and call the vars through it. quotations don't work here.
And I know this is years old, but first thing I found. hopefully no one else needs to search for a while like I did long ago

//  THIS IS THE ONE I NEED

```
ctx.fillStyle = `rgb( $(R),$(G),$(B) )`;
```

so just to clarify

Rwall = 255; Gwall = 255; Bwall = 255; break;

ctx.fillstyle = `rgb( $(Rwall),$(Gwall),$(Bwall) )`;

or if you wanted to hardcode for whatever reason

ctx.fillstyle = `rgb( 255,255,255 )`;